# How to implement cascading triggers?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have 2 classes:
Class A: Field1 (string), Field2 (number)
Class B: Field3 (Pointer to Class 1), Field4 (string)

Field4 (Class B) is set to be equal to Field1 (Class A).

Now, in beforeSave trigger for Class A, how to detect which fields in Class A, are pointed to, by fields in other classes (e.g. Field3 in Class B), so that:
a (custom ?) trigger can be executed, or
a function can be run,
to update the dependent fields in Class B (in this case, Field4) ?

Because, if this update in Class A is not detected in the context of Class B, the data in Class B will just fall out of sync!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('ClassA', async ({ original, object }) => {
  if (original.get('field1') !== object.get('field1')) {
    const query = new Parse.Query('ClassB');
    query.equalTo('field3', object);
    const objs = await query.find({ useMasterKey: true });
    objs.forEach(obj => {
      obj.set('field4', object.get('field1'));
    });
    Parse.Object.saveAll(objs, { useMasterKey: true });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, I want to automate my code. Hence, I want to detect which pointers point to an object, without knowing the schema. I don't want to write code for every single field.   So, if there's a method or code to detect which all pointers (classes and fields) point towards the field being changed, kindly advise on that. Thanks again.

Comment: You can check the schema: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema

Comment: Thanks, this helps quite a bit!